# How to compile *only* uuid from linux utils

Tags: linux, compilation, linux-kernel, uuid, configure

I have the linux utils code (can be found here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) and I only need libuuid, nothing else. I've tried setting many '--disable-' flags but it still seems to be compiling things I don't need.

Here's my actual configure command:

```
./configure --disable-libblkid --disable-libmount --disable-mount --disable-losetup --disable-cytune --disable-fsck --disable-partx --disable-uuidd --disable-mountpoint --disable-fallocate --disable-unshare --disable-nsenter --disable-setpriv --disable-eject --disable-agetty --disable-cramfs --disable-bfs --disable-fdformat --disable-hwclock --disable-wdctl --disable-switch_root --disable-pivot_root --disable-kill --disable-last --disable-utmpdump --disable-mesg --disable-raw --disable-rename --disable-login --disable-nologin --disable-sulogin --disable-su --disable-runuser --disable-ul --disable-more --disable-pg --disable-setterm --disable-schedutils --disable-wall --build="$BUILD_ARCH" --host="$HOST_ARCH" --prefix="$outputdir" --exec-prefix="$outputdir"
```

and here's my output:

```
<...build things including libuuid...>
  CC       fdisks/cfdisk-cfdisk.o
../fdisks/cfdisk.c: In function 'get_string':
../fdisks/cfdisk.c:447:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getyx' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../fdisks/cfdisk.c:447:5: warning: nested extern declaration of 'getyx' [-Wnested-externs]
../fdisks/cfdisk.c:447:11: error: 'stdscr' undeclared (first use in this function)
<...>
```

Is there any way to only build libuuid?

Comment: If libuuid has dependencies you'll need to have those available or let it compile them. The error looks like something is missing, probably something you disabled.  Why don't you just let it build what it wants and then extract the library after the fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to pull the latest `linux-utils` tarball from the link you provided, extract it's contents, and then modify the root-level `Makefile.am`. Look for the section that looks like this:

---

```
include tools/Makemodule.am
include include/Makemodule.am
include lib/Makemodule.am
include libuuid/Makemodule.am
include libblkid/Makemodule.am
include libmount/Makemodule.am
include libsmartcols/Makemodule.am
include libfdisk/Makemodule.am

include schedutils/Makemodule.am
include text-utils/Makemodule.am
include term-utils/Makemodule.am
include login-utils/Makemodule.am
include sys-utils/Makemodule.am
include misc-utils/Makemodule.am
include disk-utils/Makemodule.am

include bash-completion/Makemodule.am

include tests/Makemodule.am
```

---

And modify it to look like so (leave only the `libuuid` entry uncommented):

```
#include tools/Makemodule.am
#include include/Makemodule.am
#include lib/Makemodule.am
include libuuid/Makemodule.am
#include libblkid/Makemodule.am
#include libmount/Makemodule.am
#include libsmartcols/Makemodule.am
#include libfdisk/Makemodule.am
#
#include schedutils/Makemodule.am
#include text-utils/Makemodule.am
#include term-utils/Makemodule.am
#include login-utils/Makemodule.am
#include sys-utils/Makemodule.am
#include misc-utils/Makemodule.am
#include disk-utils/Makemodule.am
#
#include bash-completion/Makemodule.am
#
#include tests/Makemodule.am
```

---

Finally, from the root directory (of the archive you extracted), execute the following:

```
autoconf
automake
./configure
make
```

You may need to run `automake --add-missing` instead of `automake`, and `autoreconf --force --install` instead of `autoconf`, depending on the version of `autotools` installed on your system.

Now, just find your built library via `find . -iname "*libuuid.so*"`.

Comment: @s-g I always wondered if this question would be seen by OP again.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to build just `libuuid` with these parameters:

```
--disable-all-programs --enable-libuuid
```

Answer (score 1):

you could get the code from https://sourceforge.net/projects/libuuid/ and compile it. This should only build `libuuid` ....